# tabbar issue with navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I am trying to find a way to avoid this but doesn t seem to find it anywhere

I have a tabbar application in Storyboard

inside one of the tabs I have a navigation bar that goes up to three views in a row

if I go to the third view then switch tabs and come back to the same tabs I see the third view and not the first one ... any way to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement the below delegate of tab bar in your appDelegate class, dont forget to set delegate of tab bar to your appDelegate or the class in which tab bar is present.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
[(UINavigationController*)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];   
return YES;
}
```

if you are using story board, write the below code in your didFinishLaunching method of your appDelegate, then your delegate method will be called.

```
    UITabBarController* tab = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    tab.delegate = self;
```

this will do your work, let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hello
I added the delegate in the .h file of the class app delegate in this way :
@interface HelloWorld30AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UITabBarDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>{

I copy pasted the code that you have given but I get an error saying "Property 'tabBarController' not found on object of type 'HelloWorld30AppDelegate*' " any reason for that?

Comment: just remove self in that statement, i think u have not made a property & synthesize for tabBraController.

Comment: I tried it out , I don t have any errors , but now the function doesn t even get called , do I need to set-up something more than what I mentionned ?

Comment: wether ur tabbar is by code or IB, check wether u have set the delegate, write tabBarController.delegate = self; in didFinishLaunch method

Comment: no it is not by code it is by drag and drop in the mainstoryboard , and I do not understand what is IB?

Comment: then do this, in ur story board right click on tabBarController connect the delegate to your appDelegate class

Comment: I am sorry I am  new to objective C , how can I do that ? I right-clicked and found the delegate , I draged the arrow to the delegate.m and delegate.h and nothing happened ... am I missing something ?

Comment: there is nothing in it at all
 (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

Comment: do u have instance of tabBarController in appDelegate

Comment: I didn't have an instance , I added it
now the function gets called but it crashes at this line :
[(UINavigationController*)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];   
the error is in the @autoreleasepool , it is a green error saying "Thread1: SIGABRT" any reasons ?
Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: how many tabs do you have and do u have navigation controller in each..?

Comment: checkout this sample app http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58723521/TabBarWithStoryBoard.zip

Comment: I have 5 tabs and , I am not sure if I understand your question they are all connected to the tab bar controller .
I noticed that you connected the delegate to the first responder , do I need to do that ?